# R spread and aggregate

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame`, `df`:

```
userId action    countEvent
A       click        1   
A       view         2
A       purchase     1 
B       Edit         1
B       Edit         1
C       click        1
```

How can I can get this `data.frame`

```
userId  click view purchase Edit
A         1     2      1     0
B         0     0      0     2 
C         1     0      0     0
```

im try

```
spred_data<- df %>%  spread(action    ,countEvent )
```

but its return error

> Duplicate identifiers for rows

Comment: Please include code to demonstrate that you have attempted to solve this problem.

Comment: A straightforward approach using xtabs:  `xtabs(countEvent ~ ., df)`

Comment: Note that in your data frame you do not use consistent names in `action`. Sometimes it's `Click` and sometimes `click`. You need to clean this up first.

Comment: how i can group on userId?

Comment: im edit code, but how i can get nedded data.frame?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using data.table package. Data.table package is very fast compared to data.frame(thats why nowadays I for data munging, I use mainly data.table). Below is the solution using data.table package:

```
dcast(df[,sum(countEvent), by=.(userId, action)], 
         formula = userId ~  action, 
         fun.aggregate=sum, 
         value.var="V1")
```